# Implementing <key, value> STORE RPC in Kademlia Protocol

Tags: java, simulation, p2p, kademlia

I want to do a peer-to-peer network simulation using Kademlia protocol in PeerSim. There is a kademlia module for Peersim (in Java) which is good, but it skipped implementation of the  STORE procedure. 
I think it's difficult to write a module for it from scratch. So it's better to add this feature to current module, but I don't know how to do it.

It will be great if someone show me the way to add STORE RPC to Kademlia.

[This is the kademlia module for peersim](http://peersim.sourceforge.net/code/kademlia.zip).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [the kademlia paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf) first to understand the concepts.

I assume you already have an implementation of the `FIND_NODE` iterative lookup.

A `FIND_VALUE` lookup builds on `FIND_NODE` by returning stored data - if remote nodes have any - for a particular target key instead of/in addition to further nodes.

A `STORE` uses the closest-to-target-key set of nodes that responded during a `FIND_VALUE` lookup and sends data to the remote nodes that they keep in memory, associated with the key under which it has been stored. They will return that data during a `FIND_VALUE` query.

So most of what you need should already be there, you'll just have to add another subclass or whatever (haven't looked at the source).